# I can't sys.stdout.seek

Tags: python, stdout, tty

From what I know, `sys.stdout` is a file that represents the stdout of a terminal. However, when I try to use `sys.stdout.seek`, whatever parameters I give it, it throws an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek
```

What's going on? Is it the fact that I'm using the TTY itself and not a virtual terminal like xterm? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Oh, you must be using Python 2. Python 3.6's error looks like this: `io.UnsupportedOperation: underlying stream is not seekable`.

Comment: You can only seek in a regular file.  What exactly are you expecting to happen when seeking in the TTY?

Comment: It is file-like, but not actually a file

Comment: @SvenMarnach How is stdout different from a regular file? (genuine question)

Comment: @Rightleg stdout _might_ be a regular file.  It might also be a pipe or a tty or some other file-like object.  So the actual question is how a TTY or a pipe is different from a regular file.  And one of the differences is that you can't seek in a pipe or a TTY since it's only an ephemeral stream of data.  You can't go back and forth in that stream; it's not persisted anywhere, in contrast to a regular file that is stored on disk.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for the enlightment.

Comment: [`sys.stdout.isatty()`](http://images.wisegeek.com/teletypewriter.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When stdout is a TTY it's a character device and it's not seekable, you cannot `seek` in a TTY. Same for `tell`, it's not implemented:

```
>>> sys.stdout.tell()
IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek
```

However, when you redirect standard streams to a file for example in a shell:

```
$ my program > ouput.txt
```

Now you can `seek` from stdout, stdout now is a file.

Please look at this reference if you're working with Unix:

[Understanding character device (or character special) files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/understanding-character-device-or-character-special-files).